# Function behaving abnormally

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this function that is acting strange. I get the wrong answer at the end and the correct answer towards the end.

```
fun Fragment.getAuthToken(): String? {
    val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType(getAccountType())
    var authToken: String? = null
    if (accounts.isNotEmpty()) {
        val account = accounts.first()
        am.getAuthToken(
            account,
            getAuthTokenType(),
            Bundle(),
            activity,
            {
                // it: AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>
                authToken = it.result.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)
                Timber.i("Here Auth token is $authToken") // shows correct authToken
            },
            Handler { true }
        )
    }
    Timber.i("Auth token is $authToken") // shows null
    return authToken
}
```

The `authToken` is correct somewhere but I get `null` at the end of the function.
I think it has something to do with the `AccountManagerFuture`. The function probably does not wait around before returning `null`. How do I correct it.

How can I suspend execution such that the `authToken` is returned after the `AccountManagerFuture` has completed.

Comment: A function named `blockingGetAuthToken` exists. Cannot be called from the main thread naturally.

Comment: You're a live saver. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You figured it out the correct. There is a `blockingGetAuthToken` that you can use to get the result back out. While there is also a [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html) which you can use to get the result back to the main in a suspending way **using the thread of the AccountManager** as well. Like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun Fragment.getAuthToken(): String? = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType(getAccountType())

    accounts.firstOrNull()?.let { account ->
        am.getAuthToken(account, getAuthTokenType(), Bundle(), activity, {
                it.result.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).also { token ->
                    Timber.i("Here Auth token is $token") // shows correct authToken
                }.also(cont::resume)
            }, Handler { true })
    }
}
```

**And if you want to use the blocking function in IO dispatcher:**

As you're doing You can simplify your code to:

```kotlin
suspend fun Fragment.getAuthToken(): String? {
    val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType(getAccountType())

    return accounts.firstOrNull()?.let { account ->
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            am.blockingGetAuthToken(account, getAccountType(), true).also { token ->
                Timber.i("Auth token is $token") // shows correct value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on the callsite to:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val authToken = getAuthToken()?.also { goToLogin() }
    toast("Auth token is $authToken")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use blockingGetAuthToken

```
authToken = am.blockingGetAuthToken(account, getAccountType(), false)
```

Thank you Mr. Nixon.

The final code looks like this.

In the extensions file:

```
suspend fun Fragment.getAuthToken(): String? {
    val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType(getAccountType())
    var authToken: String? = null
    if (accounts.isNotEmpty()) {
        val account = accounts.first()
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            authToken = am.blockingGetAuthToken(account, getAccountType(), true)
        }
    }
    Timber.i("Auth token is $authToken") // shows correct value
    return authToken
}
```

Then we call it in the fragment like so:

```
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val authToken = getAuthToken()
            if (authToken == null) {
                goToLogin()
            }
            toast("Auth token is $authToken")
        }
```